# Nginx load balancer on same backend server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have 3 servers say s1,s2,s3 and I am installing nginx on the same servers s1,s2,s3 to load balance request to s1,s2,s3.
Is there any cons of installing nginx on the same servers?